# users have ability to approve/deny their Approval process

Tags: approval-process

Regarding the SFDC approval workflow, only a certain user and his delegates should have the ability to approve or deny these requests.  However, when I am logged in as the 'Rep' user I am able to approve my own requests.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Rep' user had "modify all" access on the custom object.